# Why Variable-Parameterized variant of (cast) operator in Java is flagged as unchecked warning and not error?

Tags: java, generics, jls, unchecked-cast

Consider the following snippet:

```java
class MyClass<E>{
...
public void checkType(Object o){
 if(o instanceof List<E>){ //this gives compilation error
   List<E> list = (List<E>)o; //this gives unchecked warning
 }
}
...
}
```

- Here, the `instanceof` will give a compilation error as the type of `E` is not known at run-time.
- Why does the `(List<E>)o` give a warning? I think this should be reported as an error by the compiler on the same grounds.

I'm not sure if there can be any case why this will not be an error and only qualify as warning.

Comment: A cast operation never results in a compilation error. A cast will just alter the compiler's "view". Basically, if we as developers cast, we take responsibility for the cast.

Comment: @Turing85 : but then why is compiler allowing a syntax that does not stand to its meaning? - it is clearly known that under all circumstances AFAIK this will never ever be true. Had it been the cast to a reified type - this still might have been a possibility - but with a **Variable type parameter** - there is no chance I guess.

Comment: @Turing85 That's not true. Casting from `String` to `Integer` is a compilation error. I think a better answer is that if unchecked casts become errors too, then many things become impossible to do.

Comment: @Sweeper true. We can only "downcast" along the hierarchy, not "sidecast".

Comment: @theutonium.18 "*but then why is compiler allowing a syntax that does not stand to its meaning?*" - The meaning is defined by the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

Comment: @theutonium.18 Also note, the cast from `Object` to `List<E>` is only partially unchecked. The runtime can still check whether `o` is a `List`. It just can't check whether it is a list of _**E**_s.

Comment: @Sweeper : then in that case - the compiler can make only `List<?>` as valid candidate  for this  operation - as it does in the case of `instanceOf` checks?.

Comment: @theutonium.18 As I said in my first comment, it _could_ be designed to disallow any unchecked cast, but then the type system would be too strict, making many things impossible to do. For example, you wouldn't be able to create a `E[]`, where `E` is a type variable.

Comment: @Sweeper : agree on this part - but if u consider the case of arrays - the type system allows `new ArrayList<?>[4]` for example - but not `new ArrayList<E>[4]` - Why can't same be done for cast operations?

Comment: Another reason may be *backward compatibility* (according to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-warning-unchecked-cast)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across this piece of code that suggests why **Non-Reified Casts with Type Parameters** can be a warning only and not an error:

```java
public static <T> List<T> getAsList(Collection<T> c){
        if(c instanceof List<?>){
            return (List<T>)c;
        }
        ...
    }
```